# Clarification about correct procedure to register a new SSH rsa key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I need to register a new SSH key between my local Windows machine (guest) and the Linux server (host).
I created a new RSA key and saved its fingerprint in a file too.
**Now I need to copy the public key on the remote machine (host) and append it to the *autorized_keys* file.**
I tried to use *ssh-copy-id* command in PowerShell but it is an unknown command.
Ok, I'll use *scp* and *cat* to accomplish the task.

`scp ./new_key_rsa.pub <user>@<ip>:/home/<user>/.ssh/guest_rsa.pub`

The first time it returns a big warning because the host was alredy registered, so I deleted it from my local *known_hosts* file.

I run again the *scp* command and I still have a warning:

> The authenticity of host '177.85.108.164 (177.85.108.164)' can't be established.
>   ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:**************************************.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Now, I don't have the [fingerprint] option, only *yes* or *no*.

I don't want to proceed because that fingerprint is unknown to me.
Is it supposed to be the fingerprint of the *old_key_rsa* (I checked and it is not) ?
Or, is it the fingerprint of the host machine key?  Which key, the default *id_rsa* ?
Or is it in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key ? (I don't have this file on a local Ubuntu 19.10 but on the remote one I setup the ssh key mandatory flag in the ssh_config file)

So, I have to connect one time to the host (registering a temporary UNSECURE key) and check the fingerprint, or maybe use VNC to check that fingerprint?
Or have I to connect through VNC (using UltraVNC) and copy the key ?

**So, how can I safely setup the key on the host?** 
(I don't want to ignore the warning as they do in ALL the tutorials/guide I seen online)

Comment: Perhaps this would help you out https://serverfault.com/a/583659

Comment: With the ``cat | ssh "mkdir; cat >> authorized_keys" `` command I still have an ssh connection "unsecure" and infact I receive the exact same warning (authenticity of host cannot be established).

Comment: You can remove your remote host from known_hosts and ssh again, you may have regenrated your keys which didn't match the previous key fingerprint.

Comment: Yes, in my original post mentioned that I already removed the remote host from my local *known_hosts* file, because I regenerated a new key. I did it manually but now I know that the ``ssh-keygen -R <remote_host_ip>`` makes a better job. Now, because I don't have a registered key on the remote host I receive the warning when I try to use ssh (or scp) to copy the new key on the remote host. It is a loop and I'd like to know how to solve it, what is the best practice (apart from using _ssh-copy-id_ that is not available on Windows).